# Error loading data into listvcoiew

Tags: android, listview

I am tryinh to load data to a listview from a remote server using a custom BaseAdapter class.Everything is working fine except that the data is not displayed on the listview.No error is generated on the log cat.
Below is the code:

Activity class:

```
public class MyAccountActivity extends Activity{
public static final String URL="http://***.co.ke/ussd/get_shares.php";
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
 private static final String TAG_NUMBER = "share_number";
  private static final String TAG_NAME = "share_name";

ArrayList shareList;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_account);  

    ArrayList sharelist = update_shares();
    final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    lv1.setAdapter(new CustomShareListAdapter(this, sharelist));
    //ListView listview = getListView();

}

String data="";
public ArrayList update_shares(){
    InputStream is=null;
    String result="";
    String key="admin";
    ArrayList results=new ArrayList();

    ArrayList<NameValuePair>user_details=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    user_details.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user",key));

    try{
        HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost(URL);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(user_details));
        HttpResponse response=httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
        is=entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log tag","Error in connection"+e.toString());
    }

    try{
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        String line=null;

        while((line=reader.readLine()) != null){
             sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }



    try{
        JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray();
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String share=json_data.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String number=json_data.getString(TAG_NUMBER);

              ShareList myshares=new ShareList();
              myshares.set_share_name(share);
              myshares.set_share_number(number);
              results.add(myshares); 
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Parsed ok",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
    return results;
}
 }
```

The custom adapter class:

```
public class CustomShareListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList listData;

private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public CustomShareListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList listData) {
    this.listData = listData;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.share_list, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.nameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.company);
        holder.numberView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.share_number);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ShareList shareList = (ShareList)listData.get(position);
    holder.nameView.setText(shareList.get_share_name());
    holder.numberView.setText(shareList.get_share_number());
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView nameView;
    TextView numberView;
}
}
```

And this is the shareList class;

```
public class ShareList {
private String share_name;
private String share_number;

public String get_share_name(){
    return share_name;
}
public void set_share_name(String share_name){
    this.share_name=share_name;
}

public String get_share_number(){
    return share_number;
}
public void set_share_number(String share_number){
    this.share_number=share_number;
}



public String to_string(){
    return "[name="+share_name+",number="+share_number+"]";
}

 }
```

Help will be highly appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: put your share list class

Comment: way of dealing is wrong man\

Comment: mind giving me directions,please

Comment: you had put you code but what's error?

Comment: you should use asynctask for network related operation. `HttpResponse response=httpClient.execute(httpPost)`. Do you get NetWorkOnMainThreadException?

Comment: No.There is no network error.Actually there is no error.Just doesnt display anything.I have put the toast to test whether the data is parsed and the toast displays,that means the JSON data is parsed ok.

Comment: @mungaihkamau what android version. you won't see NetWorkOnMainThreadException if its before 3.0. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAccountActivity extends Activity{
public static final String URL="http://***.co.ke/ussd/get_shares.php";
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
 private static final String TAG_NUMBER = "share_number";
  private static final String TAG_NAME = "share_name";
ArrayList<ShareList> shareList=new ArrayList<ShareList>();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_account);  

    shareList = update_shares();
    final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    lv1.setAdapter(new CustomShareListAdapter(this, sharelist));
    //ListView listview = getListView();

}

String data="";
public ArrayList<ShareList> update_shares(){
    InputStream is=null;
    String result="";
    String key="admin";

    ArrayList<NameValuePair>user_details=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    user_details.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user",key));

    try{
        HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost(URL);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(user_details));
        HttpResponse response=httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
        is=entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log tag","Error in connection"+e.toString());
    }

    try{
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        String line=null;

        while((line=reader.readLine()) != null){
             sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }



    try{
        JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray();
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String share=json_data.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String number=json_data.getString(TAG_NUMBER);
            shareList.add(new ShareList(share, number));
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Parsed ok",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
    return shareList;
}

}
```

Change your activity like above

```
  public class ShareList {
        private String share_name;
        private String share_number;
        public String getShare_name() {
            return share_name;
        }
        public void setShare_name(String share_name) {
            this.share_name = share_name;
        }
        public String getShare_number() {
            return share_number;
        }
        public void setShare_number(String share_number) {
            this.share_number = share_number;
        }
        public ShareList(String share_name, String share_number) {
            super();
            this.share_name = share_name;
            this.share_number = share_number;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ShareList [share_name=" + share_name + ", share_number="
                    + share_number + "]";
        }


}
```

Change your sharelist like above  it works

Comment: print the received string and check whether anything arrived r not

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to parse the results in the try section in the MyAccountActivity activity.

```
JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray();
```

should be

```
JSONArray jarray=new JSONArray(result);
```